# Check whether a pointer can be stored in uint64_t without loss of information

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits

I know that `std::uintptr_t` would be the right choice for an unsigned integer type capable of holding a pointer, but I need to deal with a `std::uint64_t p` in my application instead.

Is there a way to check whether a pointer can be stored into `p` and later being restored without loss of information?

Comment: Check if `sizeof(std::uint64_t) >= sizeof(std::uintptr_t)`? Or, when `std::uintptr_t` is unavailable, check is `sizeof(std::uint64_t)` is at least equal to the size of a pointer?

Comment: 9 million terabytes should be enough for anyone.

Comment: @zch "640 kB ought to be enough for anybody."